# how to redirect to a url from ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, rumbda

I have deployed my ruby code as AWS Lambda function using the rumbda Gem,
Now I want to redirect the user to the URL in this case `obj.public_url`.
I am not using Rails or any other framework.

Below is my script :

```
params = JSON.parse ARGV[0]
url = params["queryStringParameters"].fetch("key")
puts "url is #{url}"
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(url)
image.resize "200x200"
image.format "jpg"
 s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
 file_name = "uploads/images/#{File.basename url}"
 obj = s3.bucket(ENV['BUCKET']).object(file_name)
 obj.upload_file(image.path)

puts "the public url is #{obj.public_url}"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "I am not using rails..." -- Then why have you tagged the question as `ruby-on-rails-4`??!!

Comment: Not exactly sure how to do it in with rumbda but have you seen https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/redirection-in-a-serverless-api-with-aws-lambda-and-amazon-api-gateway/ ?

Comment: @maxpleaner its not about rumbda , I wnat to understand how to redirect to external page using ruby

Comment: It's right in the readme of rumbda https://github.com/kleaver/rumbda#return-json-for-api-gateway. You need to return a son that API Gateway understands and it does a redirect for you

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I am returning this as json:  

`{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "https://resized-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/images/dummy-image.jpg"
}`

but instead of redirecting it shows me :

`https://resized-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/images/dummy-image.jpg`

do you know why is it showing url instead of redirecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix, I added location header in JSON Dump and it was redirected 
to the new source,  Below is the code :

```
File.open(ENV['RUMBDA_RESULT_JSON_FILENAME'], 'w') do |file|
  file.write(JSON.dump({ statusCode: 302, body: obj.public_url, :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Location' => obj.public_url }}))
 end
```

Hope this helps someone someday!

Answer (score 0):

Redirect is statusCode 302, not 200

Comment: I changed it to 302 still it’s just showing the url : https://resized-bucket.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/images/dummy-image.jpg not redirecting to it.